# How do I add numbers to to each quadrant in a quadrant plot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

How do I add count of data in each quadrant.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
x_mid <- mean(c(max(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE), 
                min(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))

y_mid <- mean(c(max(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE), 
                min(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)))
    
    iris %>% 
      mutate(quadrant = case_when(Petal.Length > x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid   ~ "Q1",
                                  Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid  ~ "Q2",
                                  Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width <= y_mid ~ "Q3",
                                  TRUE                                         ~ "Q4")) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = quadrant)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = x_mid) + # plot vertical line
      geom_hline(yintercept = y_mid) + # plot horizontal line
      geom_point()
```

I want to add the count in each quadrant.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a dataframe with the counts which could then be used in a `geom_text/label` to add your counts. In the code below I placed the labels in the corners but you could set the positions to your liking:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x_mid <- mean(c(
  max(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE),
  min(iris$Petal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)
))

y_mid <- mean(c(
  max(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE),
  min(iris$Petal.Width, na.rm = TRUE)
))

iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(quadrant = case_when(
    Petal.Length > x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid ~ "Q1",
    Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width > y_mid ~ "Q2",
    Petal.Length <= x_mid & Petal.Width <= y_mid ~ "Q3",
    TRUE ~ "Q4"
  ))

iris_labels <- iris2 |> 
  count(quadrant) |> 
  mutate(
    x = if_else(quadrant %in% c("Q1", "Q4"), Inf, -Inf),
    hjust = if_else(quadrant %in% c("Q1", "Q4"), 1, 0),
    y = if_else(quadrant %in% c("Q1", "Q2"), Inf, -Inf),
    vjust = if_else(quadrant %in% c("Q1", "Q2"), 1, 0)
  ) 

ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = quadrant)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = x_mid) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = y_mid) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(
    data = iris_labels,
    aes(
      label = paste0("n = ", n),
      x = x, y = y, color = NULL,
      hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust
    ),
    fill = NA, label.size = 0,
    show.legend = FALSE
  )
```

[image]